# Regex to search for lower-case Enum constants

Tags: java, android, regex, enums, checkstyle

I'm trying to use a regex to parse enums that are lower case, for example:

```
 enum TransparencyState {
        Gone, Translucent, Opaque
    }
```

or

```
 enum TransparencyState {
        gone, 
        translucent, 
        opaque
    }
```

However, the closest I can get is `(?:enum\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*\{|\G)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9_,\s]*)(?=[^{}]*\})`, but that doesn't exactly work. Ideally, it would only match the lower-case constants in a list of enums, anything except all upper-case (essentially in constant form like below).

It would not match:

```
 enum TransparencyState {
        GONE, TRANSLUCENT, OPAQUE_OR_DULL
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^enum[^{]*{\s*(?!\b[A-Z]+\b)(\w+(?:\s*,\s*(?!\b[A-Z]+\b)\w+)*)\s*}
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZqGV7i/5)**

In JAVA, escape each `\` with another `\`

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `enum[^{]*{\s*` - matches `enum` followed by 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a `{` followed by a `{` followed by 0+ whitespaces, as many as possible
- `(?!\b[A-Z]+\b)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the next word(enum value) does not contain ONLY captial letters
- `\w+` - matches 1+ occurrences of word letters(only if the above negative lookahead condition is true)
- `(?:\s*,\s*(?!\b[A-Z]+\b)\w+)*` - matches 0+ other such enum values
- `\s*}` - matches 0+ whitespaces followed by a `}`

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks for the detailed explanation of each part as well, that really helps me understand whats happening. There's just one case where its failing, and its:
```
enum TransparencyState {
        Gone, TRANSLUCENT, Opaque
    }
```

It should be matching the lower-case constants there, but I'm not sure how to match, skipping over some items.

Comment: That's the tricky part. Will update the thread if I am able to do so

Comment: [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/ZqGV7i/8) matches what you want but it does not check for `enum`. It will find all such words if they are enclosed in curcly braces. Not sure if it would be of any help.

Comment: Hmm, I'm wondering if we can combine the two in some way to have it match with the enum as the first one did. Either way, thank you for taking the time to do this, you've helped me advance this profoundly.

Comment: Will fail when developers start documenting their enum values: https://regex101.com/r/327sMV/1

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged checkstyle in this, you can use a custom check from [sevntu](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle) to enforce a specific naming convention for your enumeration constants. No complex regular expression required.

```
    <module name="EnumValueNameCheck">
        <property name="format" value="^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$"/>
    </module>
```

This will enforce all enumeration constants to be upper case letters and numbers and allow underscores.

You will have to include sevntu in your project to make use of the custom check, either through maven or appending the jar in the command line, etc...

Comment: This is the way to go, much more reliable than parsing Java with regex.

Comment: Yes, but I'd rather not add another dependency to my project, which is why I'm trying to do this with a Checkstyle regex first.